# panel background image take screenshot

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm trying to draw over an image (with the mouse) in a JPanel, this is working, but when I try to take an screenshot of the panel and generate an image of this, I only can see the image background without  drawn with the mouse.

*This is my code to generate the background*  Panel.java

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(this.createImage("/imagenes/cuerpoHumano.png").getImage(), 0, 0, null);
}
```

*This is my code to draw as a pencil over the image:* Panel.java

```
private void formMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    x = evt.getX();
    y = evt.getY();

    this.getGraphics().setColor(Color.RED);
    this.getGraphics().fillOval(x, y, 4, 4);
}
```

*This is the code to generate an screenshot*

```
Dimension size = panel.getSize();
BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) panel.createImage(size.width, size.height);
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
panel.paint(g);
g.dispose();
try {
    String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 18);
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(path, fileName + ".jpg"));

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Never read in images or any files from within a `paint(...)` or `paintComponent(...)` method as this will slow down your graphics unnecessarily. These methods need to be fast as possible to make your graphics appear responsive. Why not instead just read the image in once, store it to a variable, and then use it in `paintComponent(...)`?

Comment: After the matter of trying to read an image in `paintComponent` is fixed - `g.drawImage(this.createImage("/imagenes/cuerpoHumano.png").getImage(), 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(this.createImage("/imagenes/cuerpoHumano.png").getImage(), 0, 0, this);`

Answer (score 3):

When you are taking the screenshot, the `paintComponent()` method is called. This means it will only paint you the image. You have to store the mouse move inside some model and paint the contents of the model in the `paintComponent()` method. This method is triggered by calling `repaint()` on the panel during the mouse move.

Comment: Agree. 1+. Also mention that you should almost never get a Graphics object by calling `getGraphics()` on a component. On a BufferedImage, yes, but not on a component. The Graphics obtained will not persist.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is code that works .

```
public class PanelImagenCuerpoHumano extends JPanel {

    private int x = -1;
    private int y = -1;
    private Image image = null;
    private ArrayList<Point> puntos = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public PanelImagenCuerpoHumano() {

        image = new ImageIcon(getClass()
            .getResource("/imagenes/cuerpoHumano.png")).getImage();

        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                x = e.getX();
                y = e.getY();
                puntos.add(new Point(x, y));
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        for (Point p : puntos) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 3, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also consider `MouseMotionAdapter`.